# Can two arrays which contain the same elements not be equal?

Tags: c#, arrays, list, c#-4.0

I encountered a stunning problem today where I'm trying to find if an object is contained in an List collection. The problem is that the list doesn't find the object and returns index as -1 when I can see it right there already. I then created a custom *Index Finder* to look for the object by comparing the properties rather than a direct equality where I discovered that one of the object's properties, a ushort array which was identical was returning false when compared, but they contain exactly the same element.

The array is as follows:

> {ushort[1]} [0]13

and they're exactly the same in both except that one of the object is contained in a List while the other one is on it's own. What could be the cause of this problem? I've tried all types of different ways to get around the problem but I can't just figure out what the problem is. In this particular case what is causing the comparison between the two arrays to return false, I've tied using `Object.equals` as well as the normal `==` comparer. Thanks

Comment: What kind of array is this `{ushort[1]} [0]13`? What is this syntax?

Comment: Sorry, was just displaying it the way it's shown in debugger. It means ushort array of 1 element and first element is 13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For arrays, Equals will return true only if you compare two references that point to the same array. To compare different arrays by content, you can use:

```
 Enumerable.SequenceEqual(a1, a2)
```

Also, if collection contains objects of your custom type, make sure that these types override Equals, equality operator(==) and GetHashCode.

Comment: OMG, I understand why this does work but this will increase the time in comparing considering large arrays. Also how is it that it works for some types of arrays but not all? How is it that it doesn't even find the object in the list in some cases.

Comment: The object is simply a class which has a ushort array, a ushort and an int as public properties. There is absolutely no overriding of anything

Comment: Comparing arrays will take time proportional to array size. Regarding the case that sometimes comparison works and sometime it does not, probably in the first scenario you are comparing the same object, while in the second you are comparing two different object with the same properties.

Comment: Hmmm, so you're saying the equality comparer treats native arrays as objects?

Comment: Every object, including arrays and lists has it's own equality comparer, implemented by Equals method. Default implementation, `object.Equals` , compares only the references to the object, but not it's contents.

Comment: You don't *need* to overload the `==` operator for custom types.  It's occasionally convenient, but in most cases overriding `Equals` and not overloading `==` is at least acceptable.

Answer (score 2):

Faced with the same issue using IEnumerable property with c# 9 records like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64796648/records-returning-false-on-enumerable-equality) question.

```
public record Person
{
    public IEnumerable<string> Names { get; }

    public Person(IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        Names = names;
    }
}
```

The result of the Equals method will be false.

So I decided to declare specific class to be used in record's generated equitable check:

```
public class EquatableEnumeration<TItem> : IEnumerable<TItem>, IEquatable<EquatableEnumeration<TItem>>
{
    public IEnumerable<TItem> Values { get; }

    public EquatableEnumeration(IEnumerable<TItem> values)
    {
        Values = values;
    }

    public IEnumerator<TItem> GetEnumerator()
        => Values.GetEnumerator();

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        => Values.GetEnumerator();

    public bool Equals(EquatableEnumeration<TItem>? other)
        => other is not null && other.Values.SequenceEqual(Values);
}

public record Person
{
    public EquatableEnumeration<string> Names { get; }

    public Person(IEnumerable<string> names)
    {
        Names = new EquatableEnumeration<string>(names);
    }
}
```

With this implementation the result of Equals method will be true.