# Records returning false on enumerable equality

Tags: c#, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

Testing out the new C# 9 Records, and wanting clarification on why sequence equality doesn't work on Records?

Say that I have the below code:

```
public record Person(string FirstName, string LastName);
```

The following code will return true for equality (nothing surprising here):

```
var first = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne");
var second = new Person("Bruce", "Wayne");
var result = first == second; // Returns true
```

However if I create the following record:

```
public record Basket(string[] Items);
```

And I do a similar test:

```
var first = new Basket(new[] { "Banana", "Apple" });
var second = new Basket(new[] { "Banana", "Apple" });
var result = first == second;
```

The result will return false. This can be solved by defining your own Equals method:

```
public record Basket(string[] Items)
{
    public virtual bool Equals(Basket other)
    {
        return Items.SequenceEqual(other.Items);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Items.GetHashCode();
}
```

But am curious as to the decision behind this (if any).

Comment: The same reason tuples wont check for SequenceEqual. It does do a reference check, the rest is up to you. anything else may not be wanted and resource intensive

Comment: Records don't make assumptions on how you want to compare reference types.

Comment: Good luck on "enumerable equality" :) `IEnumerable<int> JustOne(){while(true)yield return 1;}`

Comment: Using this method in a record would be no problem, and using such an endless enumerable as a property would really be a bad idea. So I think this is no reason for the unfortunate design of C# collection's `Equals`.

Comment: @Hayden I think your question could be modified. Instead of asking the design reason, you may just ask how to solve the issue with array comparison and then write your own answer with the equals override. I think it would have more value, and should be flagged as duplicate.